# Issue with java array not identifying maximum number

Tags: java, arrays

This code is entirely completed. I'm having an issue where the maximum number is being selected and printed as the number right before the maximum. I can't seem to figure out how to make the program print out the actual maximum. For clarification, I'm not looking for an answer to my homework as the code is 99.9% done, I just need assistance on this one issue.
Here's the code:

```java
package Zivkovic7;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {
    private static Random rand = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] randomEight = new int[8];

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            //Get a random number between 50 and 100
            randomEight[i] = rand.nextInt(51) + 50;
        }
        int[] extremeValues = sortArray(randomEight);
        System.out.println("The lowest element is " + extremeValues[0]);
        System.out.println("The highest element is " + extremeValues[1]);
        
        int sum = 0;
        int oddCount = 0;
        int evenCount = 0;
        System.out.println("\nHere is the array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < randomEight.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(randomEight[i] + " ");
            if (randomEight[i] % 2 == 0) {
                evenCount++;
            } else {
                oddCount++;
            }
            sum += randomEight[i];
        }
        System.out.println("\nEvens: " + evenCount);
        System.out.println("\nOdds: " + oddCount);
        System.out.println("\nSum of all elements : " + sum);
    }

    public static int[] sortArray(int[] input) {
        int extremeVal[] = new int[2];
        extremeVal[0] = input[0]; /* Minimum */
        extremeVal[1] = input[1]; /* Maximum */
        /*
         * Bubble Sort Algorithm
         * */
        int n = input.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
                if (input[j] > input[j + 1]) {
                    int temp = input[j];
                    input[j] = input[j + 1];
                    input[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
            /* Finding minimum */
            if (extremeVal[0] > input[i]) {
                extremeVal[0] = input[i];
            }
            /* Finding maximum */
            if (extremeVal[1] < input[i]) {
                extremeVal[1] = input[i];
            }
        }
        return extremeVal;
    }
}
```

Sorry if anything looks wonky, this is my first time posting to stack overflow. Also, if any more information is needed, i can promptly provide.

Comment: Also this is what the output is because i couldnt get it to compile here:                              The lowest element is 60
The highest element is 88

Here is the array: 
56 59 60 61 66 73 88 99 
Evens: 4

Odds: 4

Sum of all elements : 562

Comment: You can edit your question to add these details so they’re not missed :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to capture the min and max at each iteration. Just wait the end of sorting.
You failed because the maximum was always the n-2 (the second maximum)

This might help. Change the end of your code with these lines.

```java
//    /* Finding minimum */
//    if (extremeVal[0] > input[i]) {
//        extremeVal[0] = input[i];
//    }
//    /* Finding maximum */
//    if (extremeVal[1] < input[i]) {
//        extremeVal[1] = input[i];
//    }
}
extremeVal[0] = input[0];
extremeVal[1] = input[n-1];
return extremeVal;
```

Comment: OMG thank-you! This actually solved another problem I just encountered in which the minimum wouldn't always identify correctly. On a side note, I hate java and regret taking it as an all online course. It's a prehistoric mess of a language and definitely needs a good instructor to teach the content. Python is where it's at.